# Counting Distinct Managers Per Country

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Assuming I have the following Oracle database table `user_data`:

```
USER    Manager     Country
User 1  Manager 1   Canada
User 2  Manager 2   Canada
User 3  Manager 3   Canada
User 4  Manager 1   England
User 5  Manager 1   Scotland
User 6  Manager 1   Scotland
User 7  Manager 1   Scotland
User 8  Manager 1   England
```

We have a business rule that a manager is only responsible for a country if they are the ONLY manager of users in this country.  For instance, with the data provided, manager 1 is only responsible for Scotland and England, but not Canada.  I have a solution but it is slow and I think there must be a better way to query the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT manager, country
FROM user_data
WHERE country IN (
    SELECT country FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT country, manager
        FROM user_data
    )
    GROUP BY country
    HAVING count(country) = 1
);
```

Any ideas of a more efficient query that determines which manager is responsible for a country?

Comment: what version of Oracle? how many rows in the table? If the query is slow can you show the explain plan?

Comment: Is ur query executing properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `left join` and `is not null`:

```
select distinct t1.manager
from user_data t1
left join (
    select country
    from user_data 
    group by country
    having count(distinct manager) = 1) t2 on t1.country = t2.country
where t2.country is not null
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `left join` / `is not null` would be more efficient than an standard (inner) join (which is syntactically the same, unless I'm wrong)?

Comment: @ymog: Actually, I'm saying, that is can be achieved without unnecessary subquery. And as it is an example of a anti-join pattern, I've used one of the options – `left join`/`not null`. You can read more [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working well.  Just curious, isn't `DISTINCT` frowned upon, in the sense that the join itself should take care of non-distinct values (such as an inner join)?

Comment: @eniacAvenger: have you tried it without `distinct`?

Comment: @notulysses yes, with the current join, if I removed `DISTINCT` there will be duplicate values.  I was just thinking that they query might be able to be re-written using an inner join?  Maybe not, I'm sure `DISTINCT` has it's place, and maybe this example is the perfect use of it.

Comment: @eniacAvenger : take a look at the link that I've provided for the _ymog_'s question – it should answer your question.

Comment: @notulysses I checked out their example.  Doesn't really seem to clarify an alternate solution without the need for `distinct`, it seems more focused on the difference between `left join` / `is not null` vs. a subquery.  But I'm splitting hairs at this point.  This I can post another question if I'm really in the mood :)

Answer (score 0):

check stragg() function this could hepl , i have not tested below sql.

```
SELECT  stragg(manager), country
FROM user_data
GROUP BY country
HAVING count(country) = 1
```